# Can we use one project view controller class to another project in same workspace using swift3.0

Tags: ios, swift, workspace

I have created 3 different project and added in one workspace all three project has it own storyboard I have to use first project storyboard view controller in second project storyboard or vice versa. Is it possible?, How can I achieve this in swift 3.0?

Answer (score 0):

Make global variables like so:

```
let firstStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "<First Storyboard name>", bundle: nil)
let secondStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "<Second Storyboard name>", bundle: nil)
```

in whichever file you need to access it.

This might work!

Comment: It is not in a single project that's why your logic wiil not work in my case

Comment: if they are two different projects, you might want to import one of them as a framework in the other and then access it through an import statement.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create project which depend on each other like

`FrameworkA` is linked with `FrameworkB` and `FrameworkB` is linked with `FrameworkA`. This setup create dependecy circle.

You can create two frameworks but only one of them can know about other:

`FrameworkA` is linked with `FrameworkB` but `FrameworkB` don't know any think about `FrameworkA` or vice versa.

If you have setup like:

```
- Application
| - FrameworkA
| - FrameworkB
```

you can use your ViewController in Application project and it is ok.